# Rails: string to attribute with Dirty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm writing this in a callback:

```
def push_changed_values_to_vars
  template_variables.each do |var|
    attr_name = var.name.downcase.underscore.to_s
    next unless User.method_defined?(attr_name) && attr_name.changed
    var.update_attribute(:text, send(attr_name))
  end
end
```

But I'm getting an `undefined method 'changed' for "address":String` error. I've included `ActiveModel::Dirty` in the model.  How can I send the `attr_name` to the model to check whether it had been changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this:

```
next unless User.method_defined?(attr_name) && changed.include?(attr_name)
```

Easy.